# Unresolved External Symbol OpenCV4.0 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I'm currently trying to use Open CV 4.0 with Visual Studio 2017. I've already set the project properties as such

```
**C/C++ -> Additinal Include Directories**

C:\Users\admin\Documents\opencv\build\include

%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

**Linker -> General -> Additional Library Dependencies**

C:\Users\admin\Documents\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib

%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

**Linker -> General -> Additional Dependencies**

opencv_world400d.lib
```

However I'm getting external symbol errors

```
1>stdafx.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>ConsoleSample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::operator struct _IplImage(void)const " (??BMat@cv@@QEBA?AU_IplImage@@XZ) referenced in function main
1>ConsoleSample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\admin\Documents\SampleCode\bin64\ConsoleSampled.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ConsoleSample.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I've already looked around stack overflow and a lot of them said that I had to include highgui libraries, core libraries etc.. But the thing is Open CV 4.0 for Visual Studio 2017 only came with a library called "opencv_world400d.lib".
Am I missing something?

Comment: You are in Debug mode? `opencv_world400d.lib` is the Debug library, whereas `opencv_world400.lib` is the one for the Release mode. And, do you possibly move from OpenCV 3.x.x? One of the linker errors says something with `IplImage`, which - from my experience - was totally removed in OpenCV 4.x.x

Comment: Yes I'm in debug mode and I'm moving from an older version of OpenCV...